# How to change colors inside a bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, graphics, bar-chart

So, I have used the following code to obtain a bar graph:

```
selected_players %>%
  group_by(Player, Season) %>%
  summarise(total= sum(Goals)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= Player, y= total, fill= Season)) +
  geom_bar(stat= "identity")+
  scale_color_manual(values= pointcolor)



pointcolor<- c("14-15"= "green", 
+                "15-16"= "wheat4", 
+                "16-17"= "bisque", 
+                "17-18"= "chartreuse", 
+                "18-19"= "violetred1", 
+                "19-20"= "grey15", 
+                "20-21"= "steelblue1")
```

and I'm getting the graph in the image below. My question is: How can I specify the colors I want for each season on this graph?
Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: Try with `scale_fill_manual` instead of `scale_color_manual`. You are mapping on the `fill` aes.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @stefan use `scale_fill_manual ()` instead of `scale_color_manual ()`because you have not mapped any variable to colour in the aesthetic.

Sample code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)


pointcolor<- pointcolor<- c("14-15"= "green", 
                            "15-16"= "wheat4", 
                            "16-17"= "bisque", 
                            "17-18"= "chartreuse", 
                            "18-19"= "violetred1", 
                            "19-20"= "grey15", 
                            "20-21"= "steelblue1")

selected_players %>%
  group_by(Player, Season) %>%
  summarise(total= sum(Goals)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= Player, y= total, fill= Season)) +
  geom_bar(stat= "identity")+
  labs(x="", y="Total number of goals", color="Seasons")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=pointcolor)+
  theme_excel()+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =45 , hjust = 1,family="Times", face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text( face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text( face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text( face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text( color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.title = element_text( face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Plot with `scale_fill_manual()`

[image]

Plot with `scale_color_manual()`

[image]

Sample data:

```
selected_players<-structure(list(Player = c("Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Tadic", "Tadic", "Tadic", "Tadic", 
"Tadic", "Tadic", "Tadic", "Kane", "Kane", "Kane", "Kane", "Kane", 
"Kane", "Kane", "Messi", "Messi", "Messi", "Messi", "Messi", 
"Messi", "Messi", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Salah", "Salah", "Salah", "Salah", "Salah", 
"Salah", "Salah", "Aubameyang", "Aubameyang", "Aubameyang", "Aubameyang", 
"Aubameyang", "Aubameyang", "Aubameyang", "Lewandoski", "Lewandoski", 
"Lewandoski", "Lewandoski", "Lewandoski", "Lewandoski", "Lewandoski", 
"Aguero", "Aguero", "Aguero", "Aguero", "Aguero", "Aguero", "Aguero"
), Season = c("14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", 
"20-21", "14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", 
"20-21", "14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", 
"20-21", "14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", 
"20-21", "14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", 
"20-21", "14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", 
"20-21", "14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", 
"20-21", "14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", 
"20-21", "14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", 
"20-21"), Goals = c(50, 39, 16, 47, 42, 18, 14, 6, 48, 10, 34, 
14, 29, 46, 13, 14, 22, 56, 49, 39, 51, 23, 48, 45, 48, 50, 35, 
54, 21, 24, 31, 12, 51, 39, 29, 29, 29, 15, 25, 58, 41, 35, 31, 
1, 53, 5, 4, 16, 4, 57, 38, 33, 49, 25, 49, 36, 4, 1, 53, 14, 
26, 2, 37)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -63L))
```